# How to share a git repository to specific users on same machine?

Tags: linux, git, centos7

Let's say I need to only give access to a repository (`/home/myuser/myrepo`) to users A and B only.
I am not an administrator, so I cannot create groups.

How do I make it so that they can clone/view the repository?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't put it on GitHub? If not, then setting the permission to read access to group and others might be the easiest solution. Keep in mind that I believe you need some access for /home/myuser, which poses a security risk.

Comment: @astrochun No. It's a internal workspace with airgap.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using an ssh access layer like [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/) which:

- uses SSH
- does not require any root privileges
- allows to define, in a [special admin gitolite repository](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html), [user groups](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#group-definitions)